# How do I start off with a VB.net 2D game?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a 2D game in VB. As a first step I'm going to make a playing field (a form) on which I will put a character. The character should be able to move up, down, left, and right when you press the arrow keys. How do I start off with this and what should I start off with learning?

I already know the basics in how to make normal apps with buttons, text boxes, labels and so on but I don't quite get how I should start off with something like this.

Also I wonder about XNA and VB.Net. Can you use them together or is XNA only for C#? I found some stuff while googling suggesting that XNA for VB.Net had been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use XNA for a game.  XNA is specifically built for the purpose of building games, they have amazing tutorials on how to create 2d and 3d games, and it is free to download XNA.

Yes they do work together.  There was a pretty sweet site I came across:

http://www.alanphipps.com/VisualBasicdotNET-XNA.html (Edited: This link is dead now)

which I think will help you alot.  As for learning, I would look into how to program in c#, I find that it is much easier to program with, and has a lot more people who use it to help you.  If you dont know how to program in object oriented languages, I would first learn that, maybe with another language just so you get the hang of it, c++ and java are good starter languages for that.  In terms of creating games, there is a wealth of information on that, and it would be especially helpful to review the XNA tutorials page:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml

I hope this helps!  Good luck and remember to have fun!

Comment: When importing stuff from the alanphipps site to VS 2010 it comes up with a lot of errors so i think it sadly is for an older version of VB.net. I'm thinking about switching to C#. Is it hard for a VB.net person to start with C# instead? I am learning VB.net in school so I figured it would be my best choice for a game but I guess VB.net is better for normal applications.

Comment: I would say that c# is harder than VB, but in the long run I think that may be more helpful for you.  The amount of time that you may spend looking for helps and hints about how to do this, can all be covered in XNA's tutorials very quickly.  And yet, you can still apply the same concepts that you are learning in class on VB towards c#.  Also, the errors may have occurred because you may have forgotten to add reference links, which tell the compiler, what packages you are using.